# Foreign key constrain t is incorrectly formed in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.4

In my Education Management website there are 3 three tables called users,marks ,subjects.I want to retrieve marks of a student for that particular subject.for that i set foreign keys in migrations.when i try "php artisan migrate;" command it gives following error.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `nimnaya3`.`#sql-514_eb` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constrain
  t is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `marks` add constraint `marks_subject_id_foreign` foreign key (`subject
  _id`) references `subjects` (`id`))

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `nimnaya3`.`#sql-514_eb` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constrain
  t is incorrectly formed")

marks table

     public function up()
        {
           Schema::create('marks', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('markid');
                $table->string('marks');
                 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

                $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects');
                //$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            });
        }

subject table



    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('subject_id');
                $table->string('subject_name');
                $table->string('grade_id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            });

users table

    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->boolean('usertype');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('lname');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('verifyToken');
                 $table->boolean('status');
                  $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
                $table->date('dob');
                $table->string('school');
                $table->string('phone');
                $table->string('gender');
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is the sequence in which tables are created?

Comment: user,subject,marks  .this is in laravel migration folder.it auto migrate tables

Comment: In `subject` table you have `subject_id` but in the marks table your are using `id` in foreign key constraints.

Comment: `$table->foreign('subject_id')->references('subject_id')->on('subjects');`

Comment: thank you @ Ajay Singh Deopa .is it use two foriegn keys in one table